# we are getting dynamic embedding URL from tableau which will change for each date then how to create the static embedding url for iframe from tableau?

Tags: java, iframe, tableau-api, embedding

1.http://www.xyztableauserver.com/t/views/Metric_Analytics/ded99aca-fe2e-4eaa-a8ae-82f887a8b57c/3ba819a4-ffb6-4924-842b-9648dc67f1b0

2.http://www.xyztableauserver.com/t/views/Metric_Analytics/cacf4df2-1fac-426d-9970-e926333a7baf/cfa87176-fa4c-4d6f-8da9-560bffae1674

url will change for each filter provided on dashboard screen and date wise as well so how we can integrate this with iframe?